# How can I do something for each line of a file using bash loop?

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, for

```
ckim@ckim-ubuntu:~/test$ cat tt
#define a b
#define c d
ckim@ckim-ubuntu:~/test$ for i in `cat tt`; do echo $i; done
#define
a
b
#define
c
d
```

The $i variable is taking every single word seperated by space or enter. How can I make $i represent each line from the `cat` command? Either using for or while is ok for me and this is bash. Thank you!

ADD : I can iterate through the line by `while read line; do  echo $line; done < tt` but I want to do something for each line, and if I pass this output to a for loop, it's all separated to each word.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks, that help. now I can do what I originally wanted to do.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 1):

From comment from @glennjackman, I leared how to do it. This is what I originally wanted to do (grep a file and extract the file path in front of `:`).

```
ckim@ckim-ubuntu:~/U-BOOT/u-boot$ cat tt
dir0/Kconfig:config SUPPORT_SPL
dir1/Kconfig:select SUPPORT_SPL
dir2/Kconfig:select SUPPROT SPL
ckim@ckim-ubuntu:~/U-BOOT/u-boot$ while IFS= read -r i; do echo "${i%:*}"; done < tt
dir0/Kconfig
dir1/Kconfig
dir2/Kconfig
```

Comment: `sed 's/:.*//' tt` or `cut -d: -f1 tt`.  Also, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 0):

Your addition seems to work the way you want:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read line; do
    echo "$line"
done < tt
```

Output:

```
#define a b
#define c d
```

Comment: yes right. with this `read` comand, the whole line is substituted in the loop and I could do anything.(as I showed in my answer). I wasn't clear about it when i added the `ADD:`.